# Azure Functions (C#): get time zone ids (NodaTime)

Tags: c#, datetime, azure-functions, utc, nodatime

I have an Azure Function that is time triggered. The Azure Function starts at every occasion when it is somewhere 00:00 am (local time). What I would like to achieve is to find the time zone strings (e.g. `Europe/London`) for the time zones where it is currently 00:00 am when the Azure Function is running.

I.e., I provide an UTC value and it provides me all time zone ids where it is currently 00:00 am local time.

How can I achieve that using NodaTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly simpler version than yours, if you always want to check for midnight:

```
static List<string> GetTimeZonesAtMidnight(Instant instant) =>
    // Extension method in NodaTime.Extensions.DateTimeZoneProviderExtensions
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetAllZones()
        .Where(zone => instant.InZone(zone).TimeOfDay == LocalTime.Midnight)
        .Select(zone => zone.Id)
        .ToList();
```

If you need to check for non-midnight values, pass in a `LocalTime`:

```
static List<string> GetTimeZonesAtMidnight(Instant instant, LocalTime timeOfDay) =>
    // Extension method in NodaTime.Extensions.DateTimeZoneProviderExtensions
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetAllZones()
        .Where(zone => instant.InZone(zone).TimeOfDay == timeOfDay)
        .Select(zone => zone.Id)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

My first approach (prototype) looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NodaTime;

namespace TimeZones
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Instant utcDateTime = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow);
            Console.WriteLine(utcDateTime);
            List<string> zoneIds = GetTimeZonesWithCondition(utcDateTime, 0, 0);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static List<string> GetTimeZonesWithCondition(Instant utcDateTime, int hourComparison, int minuteComparison)
        {
            List<string> zoneIdsCheck = new List<string>();
            IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;

            foreach (var id in timeZoneProvider.Ids)
            {
                var zone = timeZoneProvider[id];
                var zoneDateTime = utcDateTime.InZone(zone);

                int hourZone = zoneDateTime.Hour;
                int minuteZone = zoneDateTime.Minute;

                if (hourZone == hourComparison && minuteZone == minuteComparison)
                {
                    zoneIdsCheck.Add(zone.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine($"{zone} / {zoneDateTime}");
                }
            }

            return zoneIdsCheck;
        }
    }
}
```

If someone has a better solution please let me know.